# Sitecore web Forms for Marketers module install error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I am getting the following error message while installing Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers module for Intranet:

```
Sitecore.Exceptions.InvalidItemNameException: An item name must satisfy the pattern: ^(?=.{1,100}$)[\w\*\$][\w\s\$\-]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$ (controlled by the setting ItemNameValidation) 
  at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemUtil.AssertItemName(String name) 
  at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.set_Name(String value) 
  at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version) 
  at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode, IProcessingContext context) 
  at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) 
  at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() 
  at Sitecore.Install.Items.LegacyItemUnpacker.Flush() 
  at Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() 
  at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() 
  at Sitecore.Install.Framework.EntryBuilder.Flush() 
  at Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) 
  at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) 
  at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context) 
  at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) 
  at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.<INSTALL>b__0() 
  at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.CatchExceptions(ThreadStart start)
```

Answer (score 5):

on sitecore config files you will find this setting:

```
  <setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="^[\w\*\$][\w\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$" />
```

From your question I see you are using other value than the default value for this setting. 
Can you change with default value and try to install again the module .

Comment: This is it exactly, I've had this exact issue with upgrades and you need to revert back to the standard ItemNameValidation setting